# How to encapsule text before and after <span> into another <span>?

Tags: php

This is the text I get from database:

```
 Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet
```

How can I also enclose words before and after into spans with PHP? I need to control every span differently with CSS.

```
 <span>Lorem ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit amet</span>
```

Comment: wouldn't the spans need different classes?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  From your example there is no structure to what you want to convert plus you are generating invalid HTML (no closing span on the last item).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    //your code to get text from db
    $text_from_db = 'Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet';
    $text_parts = preg_split( '#</*span>#', $text_from_db );
    $text_output = '';
    foreach($text_parts as $key => $text_part){
        $text_output .= "<span class=\"my-class-$key\">$text_part</span>";
}
```

I think you would need separate classes to treat each span differently.

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace to replace all text before the span, and all text after the span with data in  tags:

```
$data = "Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet";
$newdata = preg_replace('#^(.*?)(<span>.*</span>)(.*?)$#', '<span>$1</span>$2<span>$3</span>', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without the need of regular expressions with a simple string replacement.  What you can do is first remove all the `<spans>` by using `str_replace`:

```
$new_string = str_replace('<span>', '', $string_from_db);
$new_string = str_replace('</span>', '', $new_string);
```

Which can be also used as follows:

```
$new_string = str_replace(array('<span>', '</span>'), '', $string_from_db);
```

And then put the `<span>` again on the whole string:

```
$new_string = '<span>' . $new_string . '</span>';
```

Which will result into the following:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

**Since you did not specify that you need a different class for each span I think that having the text enclosed in a single span would work the same for you**

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode function in php.

```
$str =  "Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet";
$sp = explode("<span>",$str);
$sp1 = explode("</span>",$str);
preg_match_all('/<span>.*?<\/span>/is', $str, $matches);
echo "<span>".$sp[0]."</span> ".$matches[0][0]." <span>".$sp1[1]."</span>";
```

Result:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum </span> <span>dolor</span> <span> sit amet</span>
```